# Better way to expose methods

Tags: java, web-services, architecture, database-management

I'm writing a database manager layer of a web service.
I have to decide ho to implement my library: this is the situation.
I have a class, PersistenceUnit:

```
private static RazoooCore rc;
private static DBInstance db;
protected ODatabaseDocumentTx getDb(){return db;}
protected RazoooCooore getRc(){return rc;}

public static void startPersistence (){
    //here I get an instance of rc and db
}
```

that start my db service and allow me to connect to it. What I want is to write class that implement persistence method, like addUser(...), or deleteFile(...) and so on. 
My doubt is how to realize these method. Because I have two big classes of operations (one on users and the other on files) I thought to create to class (User and File) and to implement public static method on them, or, and is the same, create two singleton.then the application layer will have to call method without having to create and destroy object each time. 
Is this a good way to realize my layer? Is, in this way, well handled concurrency, or is there a better way (perhaps a pattern) to maximize performance and multithreading?
Certainly this is not a memory-bound layer, because upper layer doesn't have to continuously
create object.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There were lots of discussions about if an object should (or not) be responsible of persist itself, this is, should an User class have a Save method? Well, it depends. However, currently we hardly ever see that pattern.

I think the persistence logic has to be in a data access layer, probably in repositories (UserRepository and FileRepository). And this has nothing to do with neither performance nor multithreading because both issues (performance and concurrency) are in the database.

That´s my opinion.

Comment: what I was thinking to do is to create two classes, public and final, and to place them in DB manager layer. What the user (programmer) has to do, so, is to instance them and call the right method. Certainly, being a web service, each time Tomcat receives a request for a rpc it has to create a new User and File object, but it won't be a big matter.